# Replace string pattern having space and line feeds using sed

Tags: unix, sed

Below I am setting a variable read from a file:

```
$ replace=$(cat file.txt)
```

and I am trying to use sed as below

```
$ sed -i 's|old|'$replace'|g'
```

However, I get the below error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

Note - In my case the **replace** string is read from a file which has space and line feed like below.

**file.txt**

```
line 1
line 2
```

Can't sed handle patterns that have new lines?

Comment: Are both file.txt and `old` changing each time or could you make a sed-command file with both `old` and the 2 lines? And you want to change another file `like `sed -i 'some_command' file2.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Probably though maybe with some non-portable GNU extensions but it's not what sed is for anyway (simple substitutions on individual lines) so don't do it with sed, just use awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{new = new $0 ORS; next} {sub(/old/,new)}1' file.txt targetFile
```

Note you don't need a shell variable with `cat` to do it but you can use one if you like:

```
replace=$(cat file.txt)
awk -v new="$replace" '{sub(/old/,new)}1' targetFile
```